# Split section not responsive in height

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, media

I have a one page layout template and I'm having issues with only one div in particular on a split section. For some reason all my divs are responsive regardless of content except for one. It contains my profile picture underneath the hello section of my website http://dtcm.co.nz.

Can anyone suggest possible solutions or help me with this one, I have tried to include max-height:px height:% min-height:px into the css of the @media inquiries of each layout but nothing seems to be working..... maybe I've missed something really simple........

Comment: The site is just a black screen for me. Try uploading the troublesome code into a jsfiddle so we can take a look at the specific area.

Comment: The page is loading for me, but I'm not sure what you want to have happen with your profile picture. It looks like in smaller screens, it's getting the bottom cropped off, but it is responsive in terms of nothing's breaking that I can see.

Comment: yeah, it's cropped off.... it means the height is not full responsive,I've played with the sizing of container div, and the photo separately but for some reason they wont work coinciding with each other. @jameson .

Comment: It's cropping because there's a min-height of 500px on `.split-onethird .split-bg`. By removing that, and changing the background image properties to contain instead of cover: `url("http://www.dtcm.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/davidtsai.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50% / contain`, you can keep it from cropping (http://imgur.com/CTxTW5e). Personally, I think it looks better cropped as it is, though.

Comment: I've removed the min-height:500px on the section, which I had written as that was the only way to display the picture in aspect ratio, but it only worked in the firebug inspect but not once applied to the .css.... I tried the contain command but it keeps the picture contained through all device sizes.... @jameson. I guess what I need is to make sure it's not cropping, or have a focus point where the face is shown when the div section is reducing or increase the container height and have the picture respond with it.... any suggestions? I'm super stuck...

Comment: I guess it's mainly the viewport height that I need to change... @jameson but I cant for some reason get the codes to work with properly closing them....